# Calculating portfolio's value in time with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I want to calculate (in a very simplified manner) how much would $10000 invested in a certain portfolio be worth in 20 years time. I have calculated the portfolio's return rates over the years, but I have trouble actually calculating that 'value in time' in pandas.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
        Returns  Volatility
Years                      
1999   0.765171    0.285204
2000   0.450278    0.388931
2001  -0.011015    0.253388
2002   0.217420    0.171874
2003   1.221537    0.251919
2004   0.504661    0.178339
2005   0.505883    0.157255
2006   0.608689    0.251390
2007   0.387910    0.234692
2008  -0.343451    0.432049
2009   0.921171    0.325731
2010   0.823091    0.311583
2011   0.262973    0.327544
2012   0.371449    0.176349
2013   0.542400    0.162514
2014   0.101374    0.182916
2015   0.129548    0.144209
2016   0.532772    0.151280
2017   0.311894    0.154795
2018   0.159371    0.223778
```

And I want to add a column that looks something like this:

```
Value in time
17651
25597
24576
28247
54712
27451
12547
45751
57541
54124
45127
14578
24545
11234
24578
24547
```

Comment: cmd+F "?" 0 results. What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to calculate the value of an investment as it grows over time. Assuming the returns is the year-over-year return rate, try this:

```
df['amount']=(df['Returns']+1).cumprod()*10000
```

The numbers I get match up for the first few rows but diverge after that. I'm not sure whether the numbers you provided are correct.

Comment: Yes, your solution is exactly what I had in mind. 
And the numbers I provided (beside the first few) were there just to show what I meant with the value in time thing.